# Error: New apps and app updates submitted to the App Store must be built with public (GM) versions of Xcode 6 or higher and iOS 8 SDK

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect

This is the error:

> New apps and app updates submitted to the App Store must be built with public (GM) versions of Xcode 6 or higher and iOS 8 SDK.
>
> Do not submit apps built with beta software for store review.

I checked everything, my Xcode is 6.4, Building SDK is 8.4 everything seems correct.

Is there anything wrong?

Comment: Make sure you are using Xcode 6.4 build 6E35b that is the GM of the latest version.

Comment: Assuming you don't have a beta version of Xcode 6.4, do a clean, then another build.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to build with a beta version of Xcode 6? The error seems to be related to your version of Xcode.
Probably you downloaded it from the developers page instead of the App Store?
Try uninstalling your Xcode version and reinstalling directly from the App Store. That for certain will be a GM release.

Comment: Thanks, everyone, I already fixed the issue by submitting the app with another computer that is not running El Capitan. I still don't know why it doesn't work on my own computer, I am running El Capitan with Xcode 6.4 downloaded from the App Store. I even tried to reinstall Xcode, but nothing worked. Now everything is fine, I appreciate all of your help.